# Setting a date to be null in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do I have a `DateTime` that can be null?

For example: I can do the following in C# normally if I do a test on it the value will be null

```
public DateTime? {get;set;)
```

In Xamarin, how does one achieve this with a bindable property? Basically I don't want my users seeing the default which is always the current day I would even modify the code with a boolean to allow the users to choose to show the current date in the entry portion or an empty string.

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty DateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Date), typeof(DateTime?), typeof(DatePicker), default(DateTime?), BindingMode.TwoWay,
    coerceValue: CoerceDate,
    propertyChanged: DatePropertyChanged,
    defaultValueCreator: (bindable) => null);
```

Default Xamarin Code:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty DateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Date), typeof(DateTime), typeof(DatePicker), default(DateTime), BindingMode.TwoWay,
        coerceValue: CoerceDate,
        propertyChanged: DatePropertyChanged,
        defaultValueCreator: (bindable) => DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: what's wrong with using `DateTime?`

Comment: The default xamrian code has DateTime.ow on it as above @Jason See edit

Comment: It's **Xamarin** - not "Xamrian" ....

Answer (score 0):

I create custom DatePicker that inheriting DatePicker, adding a property that can be bound to DateTime? type, please take a look the following code:

```
public  class customdatepicker: DatePicker
{
    private string _format = null;
    public static readonly BindableProperty NullableDateProperty = BindableProperty.Create<customdatepicker, DateTime?>(p => p.NullableDate, null);

    public DateTime? NullableDate
    {
        get { return (DateTime?)GetValue(NullableDateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NullableDateProperty, value); UpdateDate(); }
    }

    private void UpdateDate()
    {
        if (NullableDate.HasValue) 
        { 
            if (null != _format) 
                Format = _format; 
            Date = NullableDate.Value; 
        }
        else 
        { 
            _format = Format; Format = "pick ...";
        }
    }
    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        UpdateDate();
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        if (propertyName == "Date") 
            NullableDate = Date;
    }
}
```

Now you can set null or DateTime type for customdatepicker NullableDate

Comment: _Format does not make a good vairalbe name as format could mean date time format

Comment: @rogue39nin Yes, you can use other good vairalbe name.